# levels preserved in subset, how to remove

Tags: r, subset, levels

I took out single factor subset from a.df, which has 38 levels in field 'Rh_spps'
but in new subject, when I check levels, it gives whole list, while there is only one level
here area detail code

```
rr.lepp<-a.df[a.df$Rh_spps=="R. lepidotum",] 
head(rr.lepp)
         Rh_spps     dataset   lat  long   AP MAT
337 R. lepidotum Ole & Inger 28.50 84.30  420  25
338 R. lepidotum Ole & Inger 28.10 85.30 1445 119
339 R. lepidotum Ole & Inger 27.90 86.20 2186 124
340 R. lepidotum Ole & Inger 28.40 84.85  439  57

levels(rr.lepp$Rh_spps)
[1] "R."                "R. adenogynum" 
..
..
37] "R. virgatum"       "R. wallichii"

count(rr.lepp$Rh_spps)
             x freq
1 R. lepidotum  432
dim(rr.lepp)
[1] 432   6
count(rr.lepp$Rh_spps)
             x freq
1 R. lepidotum  432
```

as you see, there are only 432 rows and single species (factor) but the levels result 38 (as in original df)

Q. how do I move the levels
thanking you

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. Remove the levels before you begin, ala `a.df$Rh_spps <- as.character(a.df$Rh_spps)`; or
2. Refactor after extraction, such as `rr.lepp$Rh_spps <- factor(rr.lepp$Rh_spps)`.